# Generating Master Key using OpenSSL library

Tags: c++11, openssl

I have a local server and I'm dissecting my server's input SSL/TLS packets captured by the NIC. As you know, in the TLS handshake process, after the `ClientHello` and `ServerHello` messages (server hello + certificate + verification of certificate by client) are sent, the client will send a `ClientKeyExchange` message which includes the Encrypted Pre-master Secret used by server to generate the session master key. As the RFC says, the formula for generating the master key is:

`master_secret = PRF(pre_master_secret, "master secret", ClientHello.random + ServerHello.random) [0..47];`

Also the random numbers are 32 bytes randoms which had been exchanged during the `ClientHello` and `ServerHello` messages.

My questions are:

1. Which function of OpenSSL can I use to get the master secret?
2. What is the PRF in my session?
3. For decrypting the 'Encrypted Pre-Master Key' (which my server's private key is going to be used) what is the decryption algorithm? Is it the key exchange algorithm mentioned in selected cipher suite by server in server hello message? (e.g. in `TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` cipher suite the key exchange algorithm is Diffie-Hellman).
4. If it is, what is the function in OpenSSL library which inputs the key exchange algorithm, private key, encrypted_buffer`and outputs the decrypted buffer? (I have used the`EVP_openInit()`and`EVP_DecryptInit()`functions, but in`EVP_openInit()` the problem is that it inputs the encrypted key and after decrypting it by the private key, it will use this key for decrypting the encrypted data which it shouldn't. It should genearte the master key before that, not use the pre-master key as the session key.
5. Is the summation of two randoms like:

```cpp
uint8_t sum[32];
for(int i=0; i<32; ++i)
    sum[i] = ClientHello.random[i] + ServerHello.random[i];
```

If it is, aren't overflows considered?

Comment: If it is encrypted by the public key it is decrypted by the private key according to the encryption algorithm for which the keys were generated, which appears in the certificate. This will be RSA. If the keys are DSA the process is different.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for your comment. I am trying to decrypt the encrypted pre-master key using your suggestion, So the problem is now which padding should I use for the decryption process?

Comment: I know this post is a bit old, but regarding point 3: "+" means concatenation.

Comment: Lots of confusion here. 1. There is no 'measuring' here, only *generation.* 2. The pre-master secret is a secret, not a key, and its length is already specified by `[0..47]`. 3. *Both* sides use it to generate the session key. 4. The client cannot possibly use the server's private key to generate the pre-master secret. Unclear what you're asking.